# AT&T syntax store immediate number to memory location under real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

With Intel syntax, I can write `mov byte [es:0x00],10` to store number `10` to location that segment address stored in register `es` and offset address `0x00` in memory. How could I implement the same function with AT&T syntax under real mode?

Answer (score 4):

The AT&T syntax is `segment-override:signed-offset(base,index,scale)`.

So your instruction should correspond to:

```
movb $10,%es:0
```

Comment: Is this the same as `movb $10, $0(%es)`?